# Laravel - Trying to get property 'view' of non-object, when sending mail

Tags: php, laravel, validation, email, email-verification

I'm trying to send a validation email to a registering customers email address, but It is giving me the error in question rather than sending the notification email.
Any help would be fantastic! Struggling here, dont understand where the object is, and the error is unhelpful af.
I did some die and dumps, and found that the problem is in the build method of the mailable where it sends the email. The email sends, the url is correct, and the account validates, but I get this error when I'm in the process of sending the email, which prevents me from redirecting to a confirmation or log in page after a new user registers.

Thankyou :)

Create user :

```php
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'name'     => ['required', 'alpha_dash', 'string', 'max:25', 'unique:customers'],
    'email'    => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:customers'],
    'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:6', 'confirmed'],
]);

if ( $validator->fails() ) {
    $messages = $validator->messages();
    return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
    foreach($errors->all() as $error) {
        echo $error;
    }
} elseif ( $validator->passes() ) {
    $customer = customer::create([
        'name' => $request['name'],
        'email' => $request['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($request['password']),
        'VerifyToken' => Str::random(40),
    ]);

    $customer->SendEmailVerificationNotification();

    return redirect()->intended('login/customer');
}
```

SendEmailVerificationNotifaction:

```php
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    $verificationUrl = $this->verificationUrl($notifiable);

    if (static::$toMailCallback) {
        return call_user_func(static::$toMailCallback, $notifiable, $verificationUrl);
    }

    Mail::to($notifiable->email)->send(new validate_email($notifiable->email));
}

validate_email mailable:

    namespace App\Mail;

    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;
    use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
    use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
    use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
    use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

    class validate_email extends Mailable
    {
        use Queueable, SerializesModels;


        public function __construct($data)
        {
            $this->email = $data;
        }

        public function build()
        {
             $url = URL::temporarySignedRoute(
             'verifyCustomer', now()->addMinutes(100),['email'=>$this->email]
            );


            return $this->from('support@xxxx.com')
                        ->view('auth.mail.validate_email')->with([
                            'url' => $url,
                            'email' => $this->email
                        ]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: please show your `validate_email` mailable

Answer (score 0):

Seems like laravel cannot find your view file which you are trying to redirect in endpoint.

"login/customer".

Answer (score 0):

In the notification `toMail` method, the data that you're passing into the email template might have some errors. To debug the issue wrap the method from where the notification is being called that is in your listener with a try catch block and print out the `$ex->getMessage()` and `$ex->getTraceAsString()` into the log, this will help you in finding the root cause of the error.

For example,
in the SendOrderEmailListener, do something like the following,

```php
<?php
class SendOrderEmailListener {
try{ 
    $event->order->customer->notify(new OrderNotification($event->order, $someTemplate);
}catch(\Exception $ex) {
    \Log::debug($ex->getMessage());
    \Log::debug($ex->getTraceAsString());
}
`
For the curious, the exception trying to get view from non object is thrown from the `Illuminate\Notifications\Channels\MailChannel` -> `send()` -> `buildView()` method.
```